# Jump to arbitrary point on a UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, bezier

I am developing an app that animates a motion on a UIBezierPath (made of several curves).
In some use cases I need to place an item so it will start moving from some point on the route, and not from its beginning. E.g put item in the middle or 2/3 point of the path. How can I calculate the location of such point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A Bezier curve is parametric curve a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve meaning you have two functions of a parameter T over a range.  One function generates the X coordinate, the other generates the Y coordinate.   If you know the two functions, just pick a value of T halfway or 2/3rds of the way between the endpoints of the range and plug that into the two functions to get the X & Y coordinates of the desired point.

Comment: Just note that the Bezier curve length does not grow linearly with the parameter, so taking t = 2/3 will not give you the point on the curve at 2/3 of the total length.